# Python matplotlib savefig: Change font size

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some figures that I have plotted using matplotlib, however the font size is too small when I use it in a latex document. I've tried to alter the font size using the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (10.0, 7.0) # set default size of plots
font = {'family' : 'sans',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 40}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)

#================= Draw histogram =====================
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist2d(flow[:, 0], flow[:, 1], bins=400, norm = LogNorm(), cmap='viridis')
for xc in gt_points[:, 0]:
    ax.axvline(x=xc, linestyle=':', c='r')
    print(xc)
ax.axhline(0, linestyle=':', c='r')
ax.set_xlabel('vx [pixels per second]')
ax.set_ylabel('vy [pixels per second]')
ax.set_xlim([k_means_x_min, k_means_x_max])
ax.set_ylim([k_means_y_min, k_means_y_max])
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('histogram.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
```

Except changing the `'size' : 40` parameter doesn't change anything and the resulting pdf has loads of whitespace around it and isn't 'tight' at all (see image). Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks!

[image: The resulting pdf]

Edit: Adding the lines 
    matplotlib.rc('xtick', labelsize=20)
    matplotlib.rc('ytick', labelsize=20)
works for at least making the numbers on x and y axis larger. However, as mentioned `matplotlib.rc('font', **font)` does nothing...

Comment: You can try changing the figsize .The smaller the fig size the more increase in font size

Comment: I cannot reproduce using matplotlib 3.0.0

Comment: That is very strange. The code (apart from the parts one cannot run due to missing data) is supposed to work fine. At least it does for me, [here is a screenshot of the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qD4F.png) I get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation, this works:

```
font = {'family' : 'normal',
        'weight' : 'normal',
        'size'   : 22}
matplotlib.rc('font', **font)
```

I'm guessing the problem was that `'family' : 'sans'` isn't recognised by my python.

Answer (score 1):

You can change axes labels directly using this:

`ax.set_ylabel('vx [pixels per second]', fontsize=40)`